# Integrating UIKit into Vuepress

Tags: getuikit, vuepress

I have a working example of UIKit and webpack, but I now want to port it over into a Vuepress install. Vuepress has webpack built in and from the documentation I am struggling to figure out how I might implement [GetUIKit](https://getuikit.com/) into Vuepress.

Can someone help me with a quick example or point me in the right direction please?

EDIT: Forgot to mention I don't want to link to CDN urls. I want the scss and js as part of my build process.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a theme with UIKit and import the CSS files. [Click here](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/writing-a-theme.html) to learn how to create a theme.

Recently I created my own theme, [click here](https://github.com/gabrielwillemann/vuepress-theme-material-free) to see the source code.

Or you can inherited any theme and customize the look. [Click here](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/theme/inheritance.html#motivation) to see how to inherited a theme.